# How to query to check to whom my record is assigned for approval?

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process, approval-step, approval-history

How to query to check to whom my record is assigned for approval ? I mean, using query, can we find out actual approver, Assigned to and status as Pending....etc. that are already present in Approval History of a record ?????

---

I am trying to update status field in an object when its record is submitted for approval and the record status is Open, approval status is Pending, and the record is reassigned from a queue to a particular user.

{ List<Opportunity_Support_Request__c> osr = [select id from Opportunity_Support_Request__c where status__c = 'Open' and RecordTypeId = '****' and OSR_Product_Count__c > 0];

List pworkList = [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id ,Actor.Name FROM Workitems  WHERE (Actor.Name='Nat' OR Actor.Name='And' OR Actor.Name='Nic')) FROM ProcessInstance where ProcessInstance.targetObjectId =: osr];

```
    for(Opportunity_Support_Request__c os :osr)
    {
         for(ProcessInstance record : pworkList)
        {
        os.Status__c = 'In Process';                     
        }
       update os;
```

}

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

By the way, you should check the SOAP API developer document for [ProcessInstanceWorkitem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processinstanceworkitem.htm) and [ProcessInstanceNode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processinstancenode.htm)

```
List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> pworkList = [
        SELECT Id, ProcessInstanceId, OriginalActor.Name, Actor.Name, 
               ElapsedTimeInDays, ElapsedTimeInHours, ElapsedTimeInMinutes, 
               IsDeleted, CreatedDate, CreatedById, SystemModstamp 
        FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem 
        WHERE ProcessInstance.targetObjectId =: objId
    ];

List<ProcessInstanceNode> pnodeList = [
            SELECT Id, IsDeleted, CreatedDate, CreatedById, SystemModstamp, 
                   ProcessInstanceId, ProcessNodeId, NodeStatus, CompletedDate, 
                   LastActorId, ProcessNodeName, CreatedBy.Name, LastActor.Name
            FROM ProcessInstanceNode 
            WHERE ProcessInstance.targetObjectId=:objId
            AND NodeStatus = 'Pending'
        ];
```

`OriginalActor.Name`Shows the name of the user the record is assigned to

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am getting Actor.Name(the user to whom record is assigned) from pworkList and status of the record(Approved/rejected/pending) from NodeStatus. But, how to use the above two lists for updating status field of my object ?

Comment: according to the status 'pending' 'rejected' 'approved'...etc, you can know the current approve status of the record, so you can update your record's status field(I assume that the field is a custom field which indicates the approve status) using soql.

Comment: Status field(indicates the record is submitted for approval or not/Open/Completed etc.) is different coming from my object and NodeStatus states the status of the approval(Approved/Pending/Rejected). But how to put the pworkList  and pnodeList  in for loop in my code ?  I have edited my question. I know it is very silly to ask but as a beginner it is very difficult for me.

Comment: Basically, if we use only one object, then its easier to update a field but here we are using 3 different objects and I dont know how my object is linked with ProcessInstanceWorkitem and ProcessInstanceNode. Can you please guide me ?

Comment: Well, the ProcessInstanceWorkitem & ProcessInstanceNode is only used to indicate the current indicate status. Your record's status should be updated by obj = [Select Id from customObj__c where id = :id];  obj.status = 'XXX; update obj. Simple as that.

Comment: The record's status should be updated by obj(only when the record approval asignee/Actor name = 'Nic'). How to do this part ? Please help !!